Can't reference builder.ConfigurationBuilder after updating from .net 6 to .net 8
Here's the error:

After a ton of wasted time I finally narrowed down the issue to this line of code:
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        // If I comment out this line of code the project will run
        builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
       // ...
    }
}

I've found that if I reference builder.ConfigurationBuilder at all the error appears. I saw a similar post to this one, but it was for isolated and this is not isolated.
Originally I updated this project from .net 6 to .net 8 on another laptop and I believe it worked fine. But after getting a new laptop and getting this project fresh from source control again I am running into this issue.
I've ensured that the correct version of Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions is referenced, but I still get this error.
I also started a brand new project and added a Startup class with the same line of code, and it produces the same results. Is there some different way I should be adding the Startup code in .net 8?

Provide the error in text format.

Remove <Nullable>enable</Nullable> in .csproj.

Are you using in-process or isolated functions? Isolated doesn't uses this kind of startup anymore

@JulianHüppauff This is not isolated (I did mention that in the post)

Remove <Nullable>enable</Nullable> if you have it in .csproj(incase of Durable functions).
This error sometimes can be resolved by deleting bin and obj folders, rebuild the project again as mentioned in GitHub issue.
Update your .csproj as below:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I have created a .NET 8.0 In-process Azure function with Startup class and implemented your code as below.
Startup class:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp.Startup))]

namespace FunctionApp
{
        public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
        {
            public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
            {
                builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
            }
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }

    }

    public interface IMyService
        {
            string GetMessage();
        }

        public class MyService : IMyService
        {
            public string GetMessage() => "Hello from MyService!";
        }
}

Function.cs:
 public class Function1
 {
     private readonly IMyService _myService;
     private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

     // Constructor injects both the service and configuration
     public Function1(IMyService myService, IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         _myService = myService;
         _configuration = configuration;
     }
     [FunctionName("Function1")]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
         [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
         ILogger log)
     {
         log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

         log.LogInformation($"Message from MyService: {_myService.GetMessage()}");

         string mySetting = _configuration["Setting1"];
         log.LogInformation($"Configuration value 'Setting1': {mySetting}");

         string name = req.Query["name"];

         string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
         dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
         name = name ?? data?.name;

         string responseMessage =  $"Hi {name}, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully." ;

         return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
     }
 }

local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": "1",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "Setting1": "Value"
  }
}

Console Output:
Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7146/api/Function1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-11-28T10:04:27.285Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000xxxxCC'.
[2024-11-28T10:04:32.875Z] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=694d84e8-f229-4f00-af98-812cfb115b30)
[2024-11-28T10:04:32.936Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-11-28T10:04:32.941Z] Message from MyService: Hello from MyService!
[2024-11-28T10:04:32.946Z] Configuration value 'Setting1': Value
[2024-11-28T10:04:33.062Z] Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=694d84e8-f229-4f00-af98-812cfb115b30, Duration=276ms)



I mentioned that my function is not in process though :(

Strangely, my test project (which is just a new project from a template like yours) began to work after I both added and removed the Nullable setting and copied your Startup class into my project. However, it also still works now when I reverted it. I will have to create another new project and see if I can reproduce again, as my actual project still doesn't work. Very strange.

I saw a similar post to this one, but it was for isolated and this is not isolated. I can see you mentioned it's not isolated in the question. Hence, I have explained using the in-process function. And Startup class available only for In Process functions.

Did you try deleting obj and bin folders of your project?

My apologies... my brain wasn't functioning earlier. When I read "in process" my brain was thinking "isolated". Definitely ignore that comment!

Yes, I did try deleting obj and bin folders. As soon as I get a chance I am going to start a new project from scratch and make sure I'm properly isolating what the offending code is because it's very strange that I was able to repro once but then after copy/pasting your Startup.cs it began to work and still works since I've reverted the code. I will give an update then.

In my real project, I cleared the Nuget packages via Tools/Options/NuGet PackageManager/General -> Clear All Nuget Storage. After restoring the packages, I had to restart Visual Studio twice (once b/c doing this just really screwed with VS's cache and intellisense, and a 2nd time because it kept telling me I couldn't run a Console project). The 3rd time stuff seems to work now. I will update further tomorrow.

Oh, I also had to add "FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": "1" to my local settings.

Is the issue resolved now?

Yes, it seems the primary issue was just adding the FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED setting. However, I absolutely believe I had added it previously and things weren't working leading me to clear nuget packages after which the project worked. This may have been due to trying various things that left the nuget package store out of whack? But when cloning a fresh copy, all I had to do was add this setting.

Correct, it could be due to the cache. You can clean and rebuild the solution to fix it.
